# Android - Error says: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: Toast.maketest() function in DataBaseHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I was implementing a Toast method in the DatabaseHandler.kt class in android but the error came out that None of the functions can be called with the arguments supplied that is the Toast.makeTest() function.
The code is as below:

```
package com.example.pama.pamaDB


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt
import java.util.regex.Pattern

const val dbname = "UserDb"
const val tbname = "Users"
const val col_username = "username"
const val col_email = "email"
const val col_passwordHash = "passwordHash" // Store hashed password instead of plain text
const val col_id = "id"

class DatabaseHandler(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbname, null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tbname + "(" +
                col_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                col_username + " VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE," + // Enforce unique usernames
                col_email + " VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE," + // Enforce unique emails
                col_passwordHash + " VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL" + // Store hashed password securely
                ")"
        db?.execSQL(createTable)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // TODO: Implement migration logic if needed
    }

    // Securely inserts a new user with password hashing
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun insertData(user: Users) {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()
        val context = this

        // Validate email format:
        if (!isValidEmail(user.email)) {

            val context = this
            val text: CharSequence = "Invalid Email Format"
            val duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            val toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)
            toast.show()
        }

        // Enforce unique username and email:
        if (isUsernameUnique(user.username) && isEmailUnique(user.email)) {
            // Hash password securely using BCrypt algorithm
            val workFactor = 12
            user.passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(user.password, BCrypt.gensalt(workFactor)) // Implement secure hashing
            cv.put(col_username, user.username)
            cv.put(col_email, user.email)
            cv.put(col_passwordHash, user.passwordHash as String)

            val result = db.insert(tbname, null, cv)

            if (result == -1L) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Username or email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }



    private fun requireContext() {
        val context: Context
        return
    }


    private fun isEmailUnique(email: String): Boolean {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbname WHERE $col_email = ?"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, arrayOf(email))

        return if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val count = cursor.getInt(0)
            cursor.close()
            count == 0 // Username is unique if count is 0
        } else {
            cursor.close()
            false // Error checking: assume non-unique if query fails
        }
    }


    private fun isUsernameUnique(username: String): Boolean {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbname WHERE $col_username = ?"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, arrayOf(username))

        return if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val count = cursor.getInt(0)
            cursor.close()
            count == 0 // Username is unique if count is 0
        } else {
            cursor.close()
            false // Error checking: assume non-unique if query fails
        }

    }

    // Securely finds a user by username with password comparison
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    fun findUserByUsername(username: String): Users? {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val query = "SELECT * FROM $tbname WHERE $col_username = ?"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, arrayOf(username))

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val user = Users(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_id)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_username)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_email)),
                null
            )


            // Securely compare entered password with stored hash using BCrypt:
            return if (BCrypt.checkpw(col_passwordHash, user.passwordHash.toString())) {
                cursor.close()
                return user
            } else {
                // Invalid password
                cursor.close()
                null
            }
        } else {
            cursor.close()
            return null
        }
    }

    // Optimized email validation with Pattern:
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    private fun isValidEmail(email: String): Boolean {
        val emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"

        // Optimize using Pattern for repeated validation:
        val pattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex)
        return pattern.matcher(email).matches()
    }
}
```

I tried to use this keyword directly in place of context as a variable but nothing changed.Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`val context=this` results in context **not being a `Context`** but it will be an instance of a **`DatabaseHandler` object**; hence the issue.

- i.e. ***this** is used to refer to the current instance of a class, the class is an instance of the `DatabaseHandler` class.*

You need a means of either passing the Context to the functions that use a Context or a means of retrieving the appropriate Context, which could be more difficult to retrieve correctly.

Perhaps something like:-

```
fun insertData(user: Users, context: Context) {
    ....
}
```

- without the line `val context=this`

**Simple Demo**

Using a cut down version of the DatabaseHandler as per:-

```
class DatabaseHandler(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbname, null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tbname + "(" +
                col_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                col_username + " VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE," + // Enforce unique usernames
                col_email + " VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE," + // Enforce unique emails
                col_passwordHash + " VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL" + // Store hashed password securely
                ")"
        db?.execSQL(createTable)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // TODO: Implement migration logic if needed
    }

    // Securely inserts a new user with password hashing
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun insertData(user: Users, context: Context) {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()

        // Validate email format:
        //if (!isValidEmail(user.email)) {

            //val context = this
            val text: CharSequence = "Invalid Email Format"
            val duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            val toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)
            toast.show()
        //}
    }
}
```

And come Activity code (which can be cast as a Context):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(this)
        databaseHandler.insertData(Users(100,"Fred","fred@fredmail.moc","blah"),this)
        databaseHandler.insertData(Users(200,"Mary","mary@marymail.moc","blah"),this)
        databaseHandler.insertData(Users(300,"Jane","jane@janelmail.moc","blah"),this)
    }
}
```

- noting the use of the DatabaseHandler instance's `insertData` function

When run then :-

[image]

- the Toast appears